# HTML Purifier & CodeIgniter quotation marks

Tags: codeigniter, htmlpurifier, quotation-marks

Basicly i got the simple text to be put in a as title of BLOG post ->

```
This is some random title with "quotation" marks
```

the result i get is this

```
This is some random title with
```

HTML Purifier cuts everything after 1st quotation mark, i am looking for a way to have quotation marks and no too cut off the string after them.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you running HTML Purifier on non-HTML content? Just HTML escape the title. This is for a `<title>` right?

Comment: actualy , this title is shown in an input field that has this title as set as value so the problem is in the double quotation marks that appear in HTML code...

value = "some "value" not showing "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$clean = htmlspecialchars(
 'This is some random title with "quotation" marks',
  ENT_QUOTES, 
 "UTF-8"
);
```